# Probability of any given student being chosen in this question

Tags: probability

This question from my textbook

> Three high schools have senior classes of size 100, 400, 500. Scheme A:
>   make a list of all 1000 students and choose one randomly; Scheme B: pick a school at random then a
>   student at random;

Makes the comparison by showing that choosing a student from one of the high-schools is different across the two schemes

> In
>   Scheme A each person in first school is chosen with probability 1/1000; in Scheme B choose that school
>   1/3 of the time, and then each person is chosen 1/100 of the time, so a person in the first school is now
>   chosen 1/300 of the time.

I did not think to use a single school as an example and wanted to solve this question by showing that in general the probability of choosing any student from any school is different.

How would I calculate the probability of choosing any particular student in scheme B?

I tried drawing a tree diagram where I had $\frac{1}{3}$ probability for choosing each school and then $\frac{1}{100}$, $\frac{1}{400}$, $\frac{1}{500}$ for choosing a student from each school respectively.

Is this a correct start?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a correct start.  The book answer finishes for students of school A, now you just do the same for schools B and C.

Comment: So the probability is then the sum of probabilitoes for each school? $\frac{1}{300}+\frac{1}{1200}+\frac{1}{1500} = \frac{29}{6000}$

Comment: The probability of what?  The probability that some student is chosen has to be $1$.  This is a good check of your arithmetic.  In fact $100 \cdot \frac 1{300}+400 \cdot \frac 1{1200}+500 \cdot \frac 1{1500}=1$.  What you have shown is that the chance of an individual student from C being selected if $\frac 15$ of the chance that an individual student from A is selected  That is what you were looking to show.

Comment: I am trying to find the probability of any given student being selected using scheme B. By scheme A $P(student) = \frac{1}{1000}$, by scheme B I am asking if it is correct that $P(student) = P(student | school A) + P(student| school B) + P(student| school C)$

Comment: The point is that there is not a single probability for any given student to be selected for scheme B.  There is a different one for students of each school.  You can certainly add the numbers like you did, but it doesn't mean anything. [You can multiply them, too](http://dilbert.com/strip/2008-05-07).  The point is simply that under scheme B different students have different probabilities to be selected.